# Как подключить dll библиотеку в visual studio (c++)?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

У меня есть dll библиотека, но как подключить ее в проект для использования ее класса?
Например:

```
#include <mylibClass.h>
```

Comment: Библиотека так же на Си++?

Answer (score 7):

Описаны варианты связывания и пути реализации: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/9yd93633.aspx

Если кратко, то dll можно подключить двумя способами:

1. **Неявно** (раннее связывание)
2. **Явно** (позднее связывание)

В первом случае для подключения необходимы: файл заголовка (*.h), библиотека импорта (*.lib), сама библиотека dll(*.dll). Файл заголовка через #include подключаем туда, где собираемся использовать библиотеку, компоновщику указываем на библиотеку импорта (применительно к **vs** в свойствах проекта **компоновщик->ввод->дополнительные зависимости**) и указываем, где искать саму dll (через переменную **PATH** или в свойствах проекта, например **отладка->окружение**).

Во втором случае с помощью функции **LoadLibrary** подгружаем dll, получаем указатель на интересующий объект с помощью функции **GetProcAddress**, используем.

```
typedef UINT (CALLBACK* LPFNDLLFUNC1)(DWORD,UINT);  
...  

HINSTANCE hDLL;               // Handle to DLL  
LPFNDLLFUNC1 lpfnDllFunc1;    // Function pointer  
DWORD dwParam1;  
UINT  uParam2, uReturnVal;  

hDLL = LoadLibrary("MyDLL");  
if (hDLL != NULL)  
{  
   lpfnDllFunc1 = (LPFNDLLFUNC1)GetProcAddress(hDLL,  
                                           "DLLFunc1");  
   if (!lpfnDllFunc1)  
   {  
      // handle the error  
      FreeLibrary(hDLL);         
      return SOME_ERROR_CODE;  
   }  
   else  
   {  
      // call the function  
      uReturnVal = lpfnDllFunc1(dwParam1, uParam2);  
   }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Для начала я скомпилировал библиотеку `ERRORMSG.dll` идущую в комплекте с FASM в папке `\EXAMPLES\DLL`

Потом воспользовался инструментами `MS Visual Studio`
у меня они расположены в `D:\VS2015\VC\bin`

Для просмотра имен функций (этот шаг можно пропустить если имена известны):

```
dumbbin /EXPORTS ERRORMSG.dll > ERRORMSG.exports
```

Файл `ERRORMSG.exports`:

```
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 14.00.23506.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Dump of file ERRORMSG.DLL

File Type: DLL
  Section contains the following exports for ERRORMSG.DLL
    00000000 characteristics
           0 time date stamp
        0.00 version
           1 ordinal base
           2 number of functions
           2 number of names

    ordinal hint RVA      name
          1    0 0000100C ShowErrorMessage
          2    1 00001049 ShowLastError
  Summary
        1000 .edata
        1000 .idata
        1000 .reloc
        1000 .text
```

Следуюшим шагом я создал файл `ERRORMSG.def`:

```
LIBRARY ERRORMSG
EXPORTS
  ShowErrorMessage
  ShowLastError
```

После чего для получения двух файлов `.exp` и `.lib` выполнил:

```
vcvars32.bat
lib /def:ERRORMSG.def /out:ERRORMSG.lib
```

для 64-битной сборки нужно включить флаг:

```
lib /def:ERRORMSG.def /machine:x64 /out:ERRORMSG.lib
```

Осталось подключить в свой проект:

файл `HelloLib.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "ERRORMSG.H"

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello World!";
    ShowLastError(0);
    return 0;
}
```

файл `ERRORMSG.H`

```
#pragma comment(lib,"user32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib,"kernel32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib,"ERRORMSG.lib")

#include <windows.h>

extern "C" __declspec(dllimport) void ShowErrorMessage(HWND hWnd, DWORD dwError);
extern "C" __declspec(dllimport) void ShowLastError(HWND hWnd);
```

Файлы `ERRORMSG.lib` у меня лежал в папке с проектом

Далее я запустил компиляцию:

```
cl /EHsc HelloLib.cpp
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так же создавал дефолтный консольный проект в `MS Visual Studio`, добавив `ERRORMSG.H` в хэдеры

Настройки проекта:

```
Debugging -> 
Environment: путь к папке с ERRORMSG.dll

C/C++ -> General
Addition Include Dirrectories: путь к папке с ERRORMSG.H

Linker -> Input
Addition Dependencies: полный путь с файлом ERRORMSG.lib
```

*до запуска нужно закинуть `ERRORMSG.dll` в папку с программой*

Answer (score -2):

Функция [LoadLibrary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175(v=vs.85).aspx) позволяет подключать библиотеки. Или классическое `#pragma comment`

Comment: при том, что эта команда позволяет подключить к проекту библиотеку. #pragma comment(lib, "mylib.dll");

Comment: На прагму нет примера, а LoadLibrary - это динамическая подгрузка вместо статической.

Comment: @Iceman: Вы уверены, что .dll, а не .lib?