# Как слинковаться на библиотеку в проекте

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, lib

Пришла необходимость частично разделить сборку программы и разбить на подмодули, что бы во время выполнения при необходимости выгружать их из памяти.

Но вот ведь незадача, добавил проект, перенес все необходимое в пустой проект, поставил компилировать как динамическую библиотеку, добавил ссылку в основное приложение, и... Ничего. Хочет `.lib` от библиотеки.

Знаю что можно с помощью `dumpbin` и программы `lib` это сделать, но должен же быть способ компилировать библиотеку, и автоматически создать библиотеку для линковки?

Comment: «что бы во время выполнения при необходимости выгружать их из памяти» при том, что Вы описали в вопросе у Вас ничего не выйдет. Либо динамическая выгрузка и загрузка, либо статическая загрузка (которая получится в результате компоновки таблицы импорта) без выгрузки.

Answer (score 0):

Почему у вас не создается .lib сложно сказать, слишком мало информации.
Библиотеку dll можно подключить двумя способами, подробнее:
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/715687/188399
Чтобы подгружать/выгружать во время выполнения вам явно подходит позднее связывание, для него .lib и не нужен.