# Создание библиотеки DLL на C++ по примеру C#

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio

Есть инструкция по написании необходимой библиотеки на C#. Она гласит следующее:

> 1. Создаем пустой проект библиотеки DLL. *Это сделано*
> 2. Прописываем "using  System.Runtime.InteropServices;" **Не понятно**
> 3. Через меню "Сервис\Создать GUID" генерируем GUID для библиотеки и вписываем его как атрибут перед именем класса. Дополнительно надо
>      дописать атрибуты взаимодействия COM.
>      [Guid("блаблабла"), ClassInterfaceAttribute(ClassInterfaceType.None), ComSourceInterfaces(typeof(SPlugin))]
>      public class SPlugin : ISearchPlugin, ISearchPluginDocument2, ISearchPluginRouter

*GUID сгенерирован,* **Что написано далее непонятно**

> 4. Подключаем библиотеку XX : в студии меню "Проект / Добавить ссылку", в разделе "COM" находим "XX", подключаем ее и
>      приписываем "using XX;"**XX - существующая библиотека, которая содержится на компьютере, но как "достать" её через VS непонятно, при соблюдении инструкции открывается пустой список, из которого ничего нельзя вынуть, естественно (на картинке)**

Мне понятно, что вопрос абсолютно нубовский, но задача срочная и не по моему профилю, хотелось бы понять, что всё это значит и как написать тоже самое на C++
[image: ничего]

Comment: Там у вас описано создание библиотеки OLE/COM. Для создания обычной библиотеки достаточно шага номер 1 :) COM библиотека это весьма не просто, рекомендую почитать в интернете на эту тему, и потом ее надо регистрировать в системе. При чем тут `C++` непонятно.

Comment: Пункт 4 это как подключить собранную библиотеку к любому проекту, где вы хотите ее видеть. Ее надо добавить в `Ссылки` и положить в каталоги Debug и Release, хотя последнее не обязательно, если запускать будете только из студии.

Comment: @NewView при том, что мне нужно тоже самое, только на плюсах.

Comment: Тогда все просто, выбираете проект библиотеки CLR, дальше все тоже самое.. Хотя если это COM библиотека, то совершенно не важно на чем оно написано, хоть на паскале..

Comment: когда я пытаюсь добавить ссылку, то у меня выводится пустой список, как на приложенной картинке. Никаким COM-ом там не пахнет.

Comment: На Ссылках -> Добавить -> Обзор и выберете нужный файл dll Но! с COM библиотеками так не делается! Добавляется tlb файл, который производит tlh файл в дальнейшем..

Comment: Посмотрите, пожалуйста, что у меня на картинке прикреплённой. Там не из чего выбирать.

Comment: Рекомендую закончить на время практическую часть и перейти к теоретической https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/learnwin32/what-is-a-com-interface- , https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/com/the-com-library

Comment: Благодарю. Понятно, что нужно понимание, но когда срочно горит, хотелось как-то проскочить без понимания, видимо, не удастся)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не до конца понимаю что это за подключения описанные в топике, но в общем, есть два вида подключения DLL к другим проектам: явный и неявный. Об этом можно почитать [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/673071/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-dll-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B2-visual-studio-c), а способ, которым мы можем создать нашу DLL, это при создании нового проекта в `Visual Studio` выбрать тип проекта `DLL`, описать все нужные нам функции в `header` файлах и их реализация в `cpp`. После чего просто сделать `build` и исходные файлы как `.lib` и `.dll` использовать как описано в ссылке, которую скинул выше. 
Приходилось несколько раз создавать и подключать `dll`, но ни разу не помню такого, чтобы использовал какие-то генерации `GUID`, попробуйте создать самый обычный `dll` проект заново и просто почитать то, как потом эту `dll` подключить к другому проекту.

Comment: Это только малая часть, поскольку автор пытается реализовать OLE/COM библиотеку, то надо ещё и озадачиться параметрами изготовления файлов dllname.tlb и dllname.tlh, без понимания как это работает, лучше и не начинать.. Там ещё должно быть куча совместимых по интерфейсу методов работающие с COM..